# REST API exception handling with a loop and if statements

Tags: python-3.x, loops, rest, if-statement, exception

I wish to use exception handling for a REST API within a loop. The `if`/`else` loop works without the exception handling but once I add `try`/`except` my loop breaks and only processes the first couple blocks.

The code below is my attempt at this. The `if` statement is needed for NONE response by the API while the exception handling is for API error responses.

[result of successful API and Error API Call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8AGRY.jpg)

```
Printed OUTPUT
---------------------------------------------------------------
['#portland,oregon', 'Hamedan,Iran', '#United Arab Emirates', 'Irani, Brasil', 'NewYork', 'Kuwait']

THIS IS THE CURRENT URL: https://geocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/geocode?q=#portland,oregon&apikey=######

Dictionary Results: {'error': 'Unauthorized', 'error_description': 'No credentials found'}
------------------------------------------------------

Error
------------------------------------------------------

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/r5/kk4m049n3ts16vn25dwjnjxc0000gn/T/ipykernel_41052/796175789.py in <module>
     27         print('Dictionary Results:',results)
     28 
---> 29     if results['items'] == []:
     30         output = ('NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL',addresses[q])
     31         #print('NULL OUTPUT:', output), '\n'

KeyError: 'items'
```

---

```
iter_len=len(addresses)
for q in range(iter_len):
    geocode_url = "https://geocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/geocode?q{}".format(addresses[q])+ "&apikey=###"
    try:
        results = requests.get(geocode_url)
        print('THIS IS THE CURRENT URL:', geocode_url), '\n'
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as err:
        repr(err)
    else:
        results = results.json()
        print('DICTIONARY RESULTS:',results)

    if results['items'] == []:
        output = ('NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL',addresses[q])
        append_list_as_row(output_filename, output)
        continue
    else:
        output = (
        results['items'][0]['position']['lat'],
        results['items'][0]['position']['lng'],
        results['items'][0]['address']['countryCode'],
        results['items'][0]['address']['countryName'],
        addresses[q]
        )

    print('GEOCODED LIST:', output), '\n'
    append_list_as_row(output_filename, output)
```

Comment: breaks how? whats `epr()`? your exception isn't actually handled! if the get request fails then `results` is unset and your `if` statements will fail.

Comment: your if/else are not skipped in the code you posted. if your if/else ARE somehow bypassed then it will keep using the previous `output`, if you dont want that to happen move you `append_list_as_row` into the else block right above it

Comment: In the example above, the error catch has worked and I need the loop to stop and iterate to the next URL.

Comment: then put a `continue` in the catch

Comment: Adding CONTINUE does not change the result. I have tried continue, pass, and break and none of those seem to affect the result.

Comment: then the code you put here is not the same as the code you are running

Comment: I have verified the code. It is correct.

Comment: look at what you are printing `Dictionary Results: {'error': 'Unauthorized', 'error_description': 'No credentials found'}`. your api call is wrong, double check your credentials or if this is working as intended check if your result dict has the key 'items' before using it and `continue` if it doesn't

Comment: I appreciate your comments. But you are all over the place. I have added a screen grab to address your earlier concern. Second.... I am trying to catch those errors I am processing thousands of locations and do not want to parse the data for "bad data" I just want to catch the errors and move on. This is doing exactly what I need it to do. I can put a successful API call if that is necessary.

Comment: try this then: right before the line `if results['items'] == []:` add this if `if 'items' not in results: continue`

Comment: The suggestion by @Nullman worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was answered by @Nullman. An IF statement to check RESULTS for the variable 'items' followed by 'continue' in the first ELSE block. The snippet is shown below.

```py
try:
    results = requests.get(geocode_url)
except requests.exceptions.RequestException, err:
    # print('THIS IS THE CURRENT URL:', geocode_url), '\n'
    repr(err)
else:
    results = results.json()
    print ('Dictionary Results:', results)
    if 'items' not in results:
        continue
```